# Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value of type NSData

Tags: ios, swift, nsdata

The value that is nil is the variable path, I have the file linked within my my project, and I need help on what I am doing wrong here.  I could not find a duplicate question but if there is one I would greatly appreciate if someone linked it and marked this as a duplicate, otherwise thank you in advance.

```
func Upload() {
    var path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("/Users/matthewcarlson/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/LiViD/LiViD/big_buck_bunny_720p_2mb.mp4", ofType: "mp4")
    var videodata: NSData
    videodata = (NSData.dataWithContentsOfMappedFile(path!) as? NSData)!


    let file = PFFile(name:"resume.txt", data:videodata)
    file!.saveInBackground()

}
```

Comment: How could my path be nil though as I dragged it in directly from the project navigator?

Comment: it is nil since its declaration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are passing full path as a parameter of path resource. Just pass name of file as parameter. I think it is `big_buck_bunny_720p_2mb`.

so your code should be like,

```
 var path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("big_buck_bunny_720p_2mb", ofType: "mp4") // or your file's name only here
```

If you have only one `mp4` file in project then you can pass `nil` as pathResource because as [Apple document](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBundle/pathForResource:ofType:) states,

> The name of the resource file, If you specify nil, the method returns the first resource file it finds with the specified extension.

Hope this will help :)